# How to define pair or point for these pairs?

Tags: asymptote

These are things I try

```
settings.outformat="pdf"; 
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=0;

import graph;
import math;
unitsize(1cm);
size(10cm,0);
defaultpen(linewidth(1bp));
real xmin=-2,xmax=3;
real ymin=-2,ymax=3;
real dxmin=0.35;
real dxmax=dxmin;
real dymin=dxmin;
real dymax=dxmax;

add(shift(-2.5,-3)*scale(0.5)*grid(11,12,paleblue+0.3bp));

xaxis(Label("$x$",position=Relative(1),align=2NE),
xmin-dxmin,xmax+dxmax,RightTicks(Step=1,step=0.5),Arrow(HookHead),above=true);
yaxis(Label("$y$",position=Relative(1),align=N+E),
ymin-dymin,ymax+dymax,LeftTicks (Step=1,step=0.5,OmitTick(0)),Arrow(HookHead),above=true);

//--------------
void pstLineAB(pair A, pair B, real nodesepA=0, real nodesepB=0,
               pen p=currentpen)
{
//these is inspired by \pstLineAB[Options]{A}{B} in the pst-eucl documentation.
pair A1,B1;
if (nodesepA < 0)
  {
  A1=A+nodesepA*unit(B-A);
  // the direction of unit coincides with nodesepA >0
  }
else if (nodesepA > 0)
  {
  A1=A+nodesepA*unit(B-A);
  }
else {  A1=A;  }
if (nodesepB < 0)
  {
  B1=B+nodesepB*unit(A-B); 
  // the direction of unit coincides with nodesepB >0
  }
else if (nodesepB >0)
  {
  B1=B+nodesepB*unit(A-B);
  }
else { B1=B;}
draw(A1--B1,p);
}
//---
void pstLineAB(pair A, pair B, real nodesep=0, pen p=currentpen)
{
  pstLineAB(A,B,nodesepA=nodesep,nodesepB=nodesep,p);
}
pair A=(1,1),B=(-1,-1);
dot("A",A,red); dot("B",B,green);
pstLineAB(A,B,nodesepA=-.4,nodesepB=-1,green);
pstLineAB(A,B,nodesep=.4,red);
```

[image]

I want to write a command, they like that:

```
pair A1=pstLineAB[A][-.4],
     B1=pstLineAB[B][-1],
     A2=pstLineAB[A][.4],
     B2=pstLineAB[B][.4];
```

or `something have the same function`.

Actually, I don't know how to do it.

Question: How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the right `path` then you can have the ends using the `point(path,int )` function. Since it is a simple `A--B` path, `point(A--B,0)` gives `A` while `point(A--B,1)` gives `B`.
Please find here a modification of your code, the `pstLineAB` returns a `path` so that you can draw it or return the ends.

```
  settings.outformat="pdf"; 
  settings.prc=false;
  settings.render=0;

  import graph;
  import math;
  unitsize(1cm);
  size(10cm,0);
  defaultpen(linewidth(1bp));
  real xmin=-2,xmax=3;
  real ymin=-2,ymax=3;
  real dxmin=0.35;
  real dxmax=dxmin;
  real dymin=dxmin;
  real dymax=dxmax;

  add(shift(-2.5,-3)*scale(0.5)*grid(11,12,paleblue+0.3bp));

  xaxis(Label("$x$",position=Relative(1),align=2NE),
  xmin-dxmin,xmax+dxmax,RightTicks(Step=1,step=0.5),Arrow(HookHead),above=true);
  yaxis(Label("$y$",position=Relative(1),align=N+E),
  ymin-dymin,ymax+dymax,LeftTicks (Step=1,step=0.5,OmitTick(0)),Arrow(HookHead),above=true);

  //--------------
  path pstLineAB(pair A, pair B, real nodesepA=0, real nodesepB=nodesepA)
  {
  //these is inspired by \pstLineAB[Options]{A}{B} in the pst-eucl documentation.
  pair A1,B1;
  if (nodesepA < 0)
    {
    A1=A+nodesepA*unit(B-A);
    // the direction of unit coincides with nodesepA >0
    }
  else if (nodesepA > 0)
    {
    A1=A+nodesepA*unit(B-A);
    }
  else {  A1=A;  }
  if (nodesepB < 0)
    {
    B1=B+nodesepB*unit(A-B); 
    // the direction of unit coincides with nodesepB >0
    }
  else if (nodesepB >0)
    {
    B1=B+nodesepB*unit(A-B);
    }
  else { B1=B;}
  return A1--B1;
  }
  //---
  //void pstLineAB(pair A, pair B, real nodesep=0, pen p=currentpen)
  //{
  //pstLineAB(A,B,nodesepA=nodesep,nodesepB=nodesep,p);
  //
  pair A=(1,1),B=(-1,-1);
  dot("A",A,red); dot("B",B,green);
  path ex1=pstLineAB(A,B,nodesepA=-.4,nodesepB=-1);
  path ex2=pstLineAB(A,B,nodesepA=.4);
  dot("$A_1$",point(ex1,0));
  dot("$B_1$",point(ex1,1));
  draw(ex1,green);
  dot("$A_2$",point(ex2,0));
  dot("$B_2$",point(ex2,1));
  draw(ex2,red);
```

and the output

[image]